# Getting 200 OK response code but image is not uploaded on server using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to upload multiple media on server, I'm getting 200 OK response code from my side but when checking server,image is not uploaded on server.

```
enter code here

RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile1);
RequestBody requestBody2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile2);
MultipartBody.Part image_logo = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("logo", imageFile1.getName(), requestBody); 
MultipartBody.Part image_cvr = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("cover", imageFile2.getName(), requestBody2); 
retrofitService.submitData(image_logo,image_cvr,"","","","","","").enqueue(new Callback<ResponsePojo>() {
public void onResponse(Call<ResponsePojo> call,Response<ResponsePojo> response) {

    ResponsePojo body = response.body();
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alert.setMessage(body.getMessage());
    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    alert.show();

});
```

Comment: Where are you posting to? The script will return or echo some texts/strings. Where do you see those strings?

Answer (score 0):

Change as per below in image name field:

```
  MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("cover", "name=\"cover\";filename=\""+imageFile2.getName(), requestBody2);
```

or

```
  MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("cover", "file\"; filename=\""+imageFile2.getName(), requestBody2);
```

And let me know that it works or not.
I think that second option should work.

Comment: try `createFormData("file\"; filename=\"cover",imageFiles2.getName(),requestBody2);`